# Why is this recursive function not working in my haskell enigma simulator?

Tags: haskell, recursion

-- pass the letter through a rotor
pass :: Char -> Rotor -> Int -> Char
pass a rotor offset = fst rotor !! (alphaPos a + offset)

-- pass the reflected letter back through a rotor
reversePass :: Char -> Rotor -> Int -> Char
reversePass b ro offs = ['A'..'Z'] !! (head ((elemIndices b (fst ro)))+ offs)

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that in `pass` and `reversePass`, there's nothing that constrains the index to be within the range 0 to 25.  For example, in:

```
pass a rotor offset = fst rotor !! (alphaPos a + offset)
```

what happens if `a` is the character `'Z'`, so `alphaPos a` is 25.  If your offset is any positive number, the index will be >= the length of `fst rotor`, and you'll get an error.

To fix it, you might try:

```
pass a rotor offset = fst rotor !! ((alphaPos a + offset) `mod` 26)
```

with a similar fix for `reversePass`.